# Changing pixel values using keyboard arrows in Adobe Brackets

Tags: adobe-brackets

Is it possible some how to change the pixel values mentioned in css using arrow keys in brackets?
In Chrome and Firefox dev tools it is possible to change the values using arrow keys and watch how it affects the element.
Brackets provide the option to live view the page but pixel values mentioned need to be manually deleted and enter again.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Everyscrub extension](https://github.com/peterflynn/everyscrub) for Brackets. You can use Command+Alt+Up/Down to change number values almost anywhere in your code (or Alt+drag to change with the mouse).  If you're using Live Preview, the browser will update while you're doing this.

Or you can use the [Emmet extension](https://github.com/emmetio/brackets-emmet) (aka Zen Coding). It includes several keyboard shortcuts to increment/decrement numbers, along with a whole bunch of other features for quickly editing HTML & CSS code.